# javascript comparing objects and pushing values

Tags: javascript

I have two different objects that I need help with. One containing categories of products and it is initialized to zero and the other object contains the products themselves with their values.

The primary objective is to compare the products to see which one goes to which category, and if the product is suitable for the category then the product quantity is then pushed to the specific category and the value of the category is incremented.

This is my `category` object:

```
var category = { canned foods: 0,
                 beverages: 0,
                 soaps: 0,
                 fruits: 0,
                 sweets: 0,
                 dairy: 0,
                 albany: 0,
                 mealies: 0 }
```

and my `products`:

```
var products = { 'Milk 1l': 39,
                 'Imasi': 30,
                 'Bread': 45, 
                 'Chakalaka Can': 23,
                 'Gold Dish Vegetable Curry Can': 17,
                 'Fanta 500ml': 33,
                 'Coke 500ml': 54,
                 'Cream Soda 500ml': 22,
                 'Iwisa Pap 5kg': 17,
                 'Top Class Soy Mince': 22,
                 'Shampoo 1 litre': 3,
                 'Soap Bar': 12,
                 'Bananas - loose': 47,
                 'Apples - loose': 36,
                 'Mixed Sweets 5s': 49 }
```

Comment: It is easy enough to write a loop that does *something* with each product in the `products` object, but how is the program to know that 'bananas - loose' is a fruit unless you have a list of all possible fruits? Is 'Milk 1l' a beverage *and* a dairy product? I don't know what 'Imasi' is - how would your program know?

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution can be iterate through products object and check what product should go in which category. Please see following answer - 
https://jsbin.com/joxogiseno/edit?js,console

You can see first console outputs original object (zeroed) and next output Dairy as 39.

What's being done is finding the product and assigning its count to category. Hope is answers your question.